# Write to database without post / refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've built a HTML / Javascript page that contains an HTML Form and a Google Map. Upon Submit, Javascript code runs some calcs, updates a table and drops a pin on the Google Map. This is all running client side and works without issue.

My challenge is that, when Submit is pressed, i want to read and write the data to a SQL Server as well as run my client side Javascript.

I've a working ASP.NET / C# / Razor page that is writing to the database and interacting with my client side Javascript, however, it is only invoked upon posting a Form. I want the database interactions to work without page refresh.

Which technology is best suited to achieve this? Whatever it is, it must be able to be invoked by my client side Javascript

Cheers in advance

Comment: You should use ajax

Comment: You should use AJAX. Refer https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/769238/Call-Server-Side-Code-using-ASP-NET-AJAX-and-jQuer for more information about AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ajax`. Just import JQuery and then:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/example/test',
    data: { number: 3 },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

On C#:

```
public class YourObject
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

On the controller:

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test(YourObject input)
    {
        return input.Number.ToString();
    }
}
```

The output will be this:

[image]

You can use that to update the database as you want, by passing the data from the client to the controller, and also return any data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

use XMLHttpRequest  . it won't refresh the page.
aolse, you can do this way:

```
<form action="action" method="post" target="hide_frame">
</form>
<iframe name="hide_frame" src="" id="hide_frame">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in a few steps.

1.create a json object to represent your data

2.create a javascript function to execute on the client side to post the data

3.create a c# model to serialize your data into

4.create a c# controller to accept the post of the data

5.call into a data access provider using entity framework or ADO.NET

Hope this helps! Cheers!

```
<script>
    // declare the object
    var data = {};

    // add data
    data.Id = 1;
    data.Name = 'Test'; 

    // make json string
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);

    $('#some_button').click(function(){
        // make ajax call
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'http://localhost/api/Data',
          data:  json,
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function(result) {
            // check response for status codes
          },
          error: function(error) {
            // check for error
          }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

create a model to represent your post data

```
namespace Data.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

create a controller to handle the post request and update database

```
using Data.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Data.Controllers
{
    public class DataController : Controller
    {
        // some data access provider using entity framework or ADO.NET
        DataProvider provider;

        public DataController()
        {
            provider = new Provider ();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PostData([FromBody]Item data)
        {
            provider.Add(data);
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cold post your data on server side using controller form-collection like below.

**Javascript:**

```
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", "Controller/Action");
      request.send(new FormData(formData));
```

C#

```
public void Action(FormCollection formCollection)
{
   //Your code goes here.
}
```